# A place to drop custom profile scripts for bash shell to load on login? (without sudo and without editing .bashrc, .bash_profile, .bash_login)

Tags: bash, shell

I've read over what profile scripts are loaded when bash starts: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html

I do see that it looks for the well-known files:

> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

I'd like to be able to load custom profile scripts when my shell begins, for instance this: https://github.com/xvoland/Extract/blob/master/extract.sh
What I want is slightly different than what I've read on gnu.org.  I don't want to have to edit the standard .bash* files to add this:

```
if [ -f ~/.init/extract.sh ]; then
    . ~/.init/extract.sh
fi
```

**I am hoping there is a way that a non-root user can easily drop in custom shell init scripts in a directory like ~/.init and expect them to run when their own shell is started.**  It would be great if it worked for any shell, whether bash, fish, zsh, etc.

As a developer and teammate, providing shell scripts to others, and then convincing them to edit their .bash* file is a bit tricky.  Additionally, I may work on a nodejs npm project that adds this to the path to allow ~/npm_modules to be run similar to global installs:

```
export PATH="~/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
```

If there was simply a directory for this purpose called ~/.init that affected only the current user and didn't require root, it would be easy to simply copy a new file into that folder.  It is easier/safer than editing .bash* files.

Is there a way to include init scripts in this way?

Comment: What is wrong with adding the lines to the bottom of `~/.profile` (and adding  `. ~/.profile` to your other shell startup scripts if necessary)?

Comment: you can edit .bash file once and add within something to execute all scripts within ~/.init ... for script in ~/.init/*; do source script; done by example...

Comment: bash, zsh and fish are all different languages. fish particularly is not a bourne-type shell. No possible way it can "work for any shell". bash's /etc/profile sources ".sh" files in /etc/profile.d/, so you could drop stuff in there, but that requires sudo

Comment: @glennjackman that is interesting.  It seems what I'm looking for is a local version of /etc/profile.d/, but I doubt it's possible at this point.  I guess I'd need to include something custom in a .bash_profile to scan such a ~/profile.d/ directory.